# Laravel 5.4 delete one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete a record on a table if no one use it on another.

For example, if I delete all articles in a category, I want to delete this category too because no one use it.

Is there a simple way to do it with laravel ?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel `doesntHave` method to delete all categories that doesn't have  articles.

Something like this

```
category::doesntHave('articles')->delete();
```

You can read more about this in the official document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

When you check to see if a category has any articles, you can just delete the category if there aren't any.  For example:

```
if(!$category->articles->count()){
   $category->delete();
}
```